# Slow overview over time on GNOME Shell 42.9

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, activities-overview

Hello I have upgraded form ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04.

I am a big fan of the gnome 3 window manager so I installed it, I of course had to install a few extensions to make the 42.9 more like the Gnome 3 of the 18.04.

But I have a problem. After some time, (a few days) the overview starts to get slow and progressively gets worst after each day.
I have it on my laptop and desktop with very different hardware and they both have the same problem.

I have tried to catch it with htop but I did notice any thing.

Is there a way to find what is going on?
Or does any one have the same problem? And have a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: 1) You use extensions, so first see whether one of the extensions is the culprit. 2) You upgraded, so your issue may be related with the upgrade process. Gnome Shell in principle has vastly improved under the hood (performance, memory leaks) since 18.04, so we do not really expect what you see.

Comment: Sorry I did not make my self clear. I upgraded by doing a fresh install. I will try one extension ata time. It's just a boring thing to do.

Comment: Comments are there to improve questions. Edit your question and make clear to everyone reading the question that this concerns a fresh install. Then you will never again be bothered with remarks this may be related to an upgrade issue.